# How to convert iter.next() to an array index?

Tags: arrays, rust, breadth-first-search

I would implement an array `v` to mark the current vertex as visited. However, `iter.next()` cannot be an index of `LinkedList` or an index of an array.

1. The output of `iter.next()` is not an integer, it is an option `Some`.
2. How to use the value in `Some`? If I would use value in `Some` as an index of array. Should I convert the value into an integer?

```
fn bfs(s: usize) {
    let mut cells = vec![LinkedList::<usize>::new(); 4];

    for (i, cell) in cells.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        cell.push_front(i);
    }

    cells[0].push_back(1);
    cells[0].push_back(2);

    cells[1].push_back(2);

    cells[2].push_back(0);
    cells[2].push_back(3);

    cells[3].push_back(3);

    let mut iter = cells[s].iter();
    let mut v = vec![0; 4];

    // Entry point
    for i in 0..cells[s].len() {
        // It is incorrect, "iter.next()" it cannot be a index of LinkedList
        // vector "v" to keep track of which vertex has been traversed
        //v[iter.next()] = 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    bfs(2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`iter.next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) return an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), you just need to deconstruct it:

```
for i in 0..cells[s].len() {
    let x = match iter.next() {
        Some(x) => *x,
        None => return,
    };
    v[x] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Would you advise me where can I find more information about Option in rust. Because I find a similar problem with queue.pop_back().

Comment: @madeinQuant In the book, https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch06-02-match.html#matching-with-optiont

Answer (score 2):

Rust's `for` loops can iterate for you, so you don't need to explicitly create an iterator or call `next()`. The `Option` will already be unwrapped inside the loop, because the loop automatically ends when `next()` returns `None`.

```
for &i in &cells[s] {
    v[i] = 1;  
}
```

This saves you having to keep track of index variables just to create a loop. And the code is a lot shorter and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version

```
fn bfs(s: usize) {
    let mut cells = vec![LinkedList::<usize>::new(); 4];
    let mut traversal = LinkedList::new();
    let mut queue = LinkedList::new();

    for (i, cell) in cells.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        cell.push_front(i);
    }

    cells[0].push_back(1);
    cells[0].push_back(2);

    cells[1].push_back(2);

    cells[2].push_back(0);
    cells[2].push_back(3);

    cells[3].push_back(3);

    let mut v = vec![0; 4];
    let mut done = false;
    let c = s;

    while !done {
        for &x in &cells[c] {
            if v[x] == 0 {
                v[x] = 1;
                queue.push_back(x);
                traversal.push_back(x)
            }
        }

        let c = queue.pop_back();

        if queue.is_empty() {
            // walkthrough
            for i in 0..cells.len() {
                if v[i] == 0 {
                    v[i] = 1;
                    queue.push_back(i);
                    traversal.push_back(i)
                }
            }

            if queue.is_empty() {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", traversal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reference of the integer value in `Some` as the index of the array.

```rust
let mut v = vec![0; 4];
while !done {
    let mut iter = cells[c].iter().peekable();

    // Entry point
    while let Some(&x) = iter.next_if(|&&n| v[n] == 0) {
        v[x] = 1;
        queue.push_back(x);
        traversal.push_back(x)
    }
    …
```